# Google Photo Api Upload Error : "code": 3, "Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item

Tags: java, android, http, file-upload, google-photos

private void uploadToPhotos() throws FileNotFoundException {
Log.e(TAG, "uploadToPhotos: ");

```
    asyncHttpClient.setTimeout(50 * 1000);

    String token = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN,"");
    String url = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads";


    /*StringEntity jsonEntity = null;
    JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();*/
    File file = new File(path);
/*    Bitmap src= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    src.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    try {
        jsonParams.put("media-binary-data", data);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        jsonEntity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("media-binary-data", file);

    Log.e(TAG, "uploadToPhotos:MIME "+Constants.getMimeType(path));
    Constants.enableSSL(asyncHttpClient);
    asyncHttpClient.addHeader("Content-type","application/octet-stream");
    asyncHttpClient.addHeader("X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type",Constants.getMimeType(path));
    asyncHttpClient.addHeader("X-Goog-Upload-Protocol","raw");
    asyncHttpClient.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+token+"");

    asyncHttpClient.post(SingleImageViewScreen.this,url, params,  new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                String res = new String(responseBody);
                Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: "+res );
                createNewPhoto(res);

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            try {
                String res = new String(responseBody);
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailed: "+res );

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}

private void createNewPhoto(String utoken) {
    Log.e(TAG, "uploadToPhotos: ");


    asyncHttpClient.setTimeout(15 * 1000);

    String token = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN,"");
    String url = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate";


    StringEntity jsonEntity = null;
   // jsonParams.put("")

    try {
        String body = "{ \"newMediaItems\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"description\": \"test image\",\n" +
                "      \"simpleMediaItem\": {\n" +
                "        \"uploadToken\": \"" + utoken +
                "\"      }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "   " +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}";

        Log.e(TAG, "createNewPhoto: "+body);
        jsonEntity = new StringEntity(body);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   // Log.e(TAG, "uploadToPhotos:MIME "+Constants.getMimeType(path));
    Constants.enableSSL(asyncHttpClient);
    asyncHttpClient.addHeader("Content-type","application/json");
     asyncHttpClient.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+token+"");


    asyncHttpClient.post(SingleImageViewScreen.this,url, jsonEntity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                String res = new String(responseBody);
                Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: "+res );

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            try {
                String res = new String(responseBody);
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailed: "+res );

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I am trying to upload photo to Google photos but receiving error "code: 3,  Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item." Can someone please help me to figure out the issue.

I am trying to upload photo to Google photos but receiving error "code: 3,  Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item." Can someone please help me to figure out the issue.